Where have I made a mistake? Finding the canonical form of a second order linear PDE gone wrong.
I'm looking for an explanation where have I gone wrong (and specifically in this method), because I've followed all the steps diligently.
I have the problem $u_{xx}-6u_{xy}+9u_{yy}=xy^2$, I can see the discriminant is $0$ so that means a parabolic PDE of the form $u_{qq}=f\left(q,r,u_{q},u_{r}\right)$, but when I did all the steps I ended up with a different form, here's what I did:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6\pm\sqrt{0}}{2}=3\Rightarrow y-3x=q
$$
checking the substitutions I found are valid:
$$\begin{cases}
q=y-3x\\
r=x
\end{cases}\Rightarrow J=\begin{vmatrix}-3 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=-1\neq0
$$
calculating the partial derivatives:
$$\begin{cases}
u_{x}=u_{q}\cdot q_{x}+u_{r}\cdot r_{x} & =-3u_{q}+u_{r}\\
u_{xx}=\left(-3u_{q}+u_{r}\right)_{x}=-3\cdot u_{qq}\cdot q_{x}-3u_{qr}\cdot r_{x}+u_{rr}\cdot r_{x}+u_{rq}\cdot q_{x} & =9u_{qq}+u_{rr}-6u_{qr}\\
u_{y}=u_{q}\cdot q_{y}+u_{r}\cdot r_{y} & =u_{q}\\
u_{yy}=\left(u_{q}\right)_{y}=u_{qq}\cdot q_{y}+u_{qr}\cdot r_{y} & =u_{qq}\\
u_{xy}=u_{yx}=\left(u_{q}\right)_{x}=u_{qq}\cdot q_{x}+u_{qr}\cdot r_{x} & =-3u_{qq}+u_{qr}
\end{cases}
$$
plugging what I found to the original PDE:
$$9u_{qq}+u_{rr}-6u_{qr}-6\left(-3u_{qq}+u_{qr}\right)+9\left(u_{qq}\right)=r\left(q+3r\right)^{2}
$$
$$36u_{qq}+u_{rr}-12u_{qr}=r\left(q+3r\right)^{2}$$
which as you can see the final line isn't the canonical form $u_{qq}=f\left(q,r,u_{q},u_{r}\right)$ that I was expecting.

Why do you post the same question twice?
@Goncalo gave you a very good answer.

According to @gpmath please don't post the same questions repeatedly. Otherwise you have included the Approach. That's good.

@gpmath because he gave me a solution, while I asked to understand where have I done a mistake in this method of finding the canonical form, I can delete the other question if it's a problem.
i really just need an explanation on what went wrong with my method here.

@Nate3384 Because you made the wrong transformation, correct is $q=x, r=y+3 x$.

@gpmath why is that thought? the derivative is equal to 3, which means that y=3x+c, which means c=y-3x and then I can input q or r to be y-3x and the other to whatever won't make the jacobian 0.

@Nate3384 Here you may see my calculation: MSE_Q5012206

@gpmath I'm sorry, but i don't quite understand what's going on with your solution, I don't need to solve the PDE (we haven't learned that yet) only to bring it to a canonical form but it seems like it was a computer program that did it for you and again I agree with you that your transformation works but what I'm asking is why mine didn't work or how to get a transformation that works in my case.

$$a\cdot u_{xx}+2b\cdot u_{xy}+c\cdot u_{yy}=u_{xx}-6u_{xy}+9u_{yy} \implies a=1,b=-3,c=9$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b\pm \sqrt{b^2-ac}}{a}=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{9-9}}{1}=-3 \color{red}{\ne} 3$$

@gpmath wait wait wait, this doesn't equal to the quadratic formula, the way I learned it is that for $$a\cdot u_{xx}+b\cdot u_{xy}+c\cdot u_{yy}=u_{xx}-6u_{xy}+9u_{yy} \implies a=1,b=-6,c=9$$ and then you use the quadratic formula: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-(-6)\pm \sqrt{36-36}}{2}=3 $$
i guess they had a typo and no one noticed
this then explains everything, thank you very much

@Nate3384 The formulas differ depending of the type of the PDE: hyperbolic, parabolic, elliptic. See Video canonical form
